# CSS second child issue

Tags: css

I am trying to change second button background-color.However, it affects also first button.Can you help me please?
Here is my code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr class="caption">
        <th class="center" colspan="8">Name</th>
        <th class="center" colspan="3">
            <button class="btn btn-white btn-info btn-bold" title="Save" onclick="Save();">

            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-white btn-info btn-bold" title="Cancel" onclick="Cancel();">

            </button>

        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your code is unreadable and seems incomplete. Are you sure you pasted the code correctly ?

Comment: What does your css looks like? How about adding classes to the buttons that clearly identify them?

Answer (score 0):

You used '+' for no reason and forgot to assign a class ".".

Basically, reading from your code:

Get class table, its child **element** (it is a class) and **effect** (why, how? why did you use this check? It is like using *if* function) element thead and its child element .. (etc etc)

```
.table>caption+thead>tr:first-child>td, .table>caption+thead>tr:first-child>th,.table>thead:first-child>tr:first-child>th
```

Comment: How can I change color of same class name but different title and click event in button inside of table?

Comment: Same class, different class title? So they are different classes.

Comment: Can you explain to me why did you use '+'? They have no sense is this code.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the second button an extra class.  Please look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/579h1duf/)

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr class="caption">
        <th class="center" colspan="8">Name</th>
        <th class="center" colspan="3">
            <button class="btn btn-white btn-info btn-bold" title="Save" onclick="Save();">Save

            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-white btn-info btn-bold second" title="Cancel" onclick="Cancel();">Cancel

            </button>

        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.second {
  background-color: #123456;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nth-child` selector:

```
button:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}
```

But giving the button it's own class would make more sense here:

```
.btn-cancel {
  background: red;
}
```

Bootstrap (which you seem to be using) even has the `btn-danger` class ready for this, so it would work even without any custom CSS:

```
<button class="btn btn-bold btn-danger" onclick="Cancel();">Cancel</button>
```

There are other colors available: [bootstrap docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#examples).

[Codepen example with all tree cases](http://codepen.io/helb/pen/WpQrMo)

---

Btw. button labels won't work with your code, it's supposed to be

```
<button class="btn btn-white btn-info btn-bold" onclick="Save();">Save</button>
```

not

```
<button class="btn btn-white btn-info btn-bold" title="Save" onclick="Save();"></button>
```